# Standing Jeep JK - What to watch out for

Tags: jeep, preventive-maintenance

My Jeep JK developed a bad radiator leak.  While trying to decide between new or converting to aluminum retrofit (too expensive to order off overseas shopping sites - import duties), the car is now standing and as a result, the battery went flat.

What else do I have to be careful of looking out for, that the jeep does not become "beyond repair".  I am already sad enough that she is not running, but I don't want things to go worse in the mean-time.

Is there a definitive list of things to keep my hand on?

Comment: Not sure where you are, but the UK has radiator shops that put new cores into the original frame - may be a cost-effective option...  Towed my Dad's van to one shop and they rebuilt the rad in under 2 hours - I fitted the rad in their car park...

Comment: @SolarMike I am in South Africa.  New factory plastic one is around 350 UK Pounds & retrofit of existing to aluminum is around 250 UK Pounds.  I think the concept is similar - but only one I can find.